# How to truncate decimals in JavaScript without Math library?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need numbers to have only 2 decimals (as in money), and I was using this:

```
Number(parseFloat(Math.trunc(amount_to_truncate * 100) / 100));
```

But I can no longer support the Math library.

How can I achieve this without the Math library AND withou rounding the decimals?

Comment: Why can't you use `Math`? It's available everywhere.

Comment: `Number(amount_to_truncate.toFixed(2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it simple

```
const trunc = (n, decimalPlaces) => {
  const decimals = decimalPlaces ? decimalPlaces : 2;
  const asString = n.toString();
  const pos = asString.indexOf('.') != -1 ? asString.indexOf('.') + decimals + 1 : asString.length;
  return parseFloat(n.toString().substring(0, pos));
};

console.log(trunc(3.14159265359));
console.log(trunc(11.1111111));
console.log(trunc(3));
console.log(trunc(11));
console.log(trunc(3.1));
console.log(trunc(11.1));
console.log(trunc(3.14));
console.log(trunc(11.11));
console.log(trunc(3.141));
console.log(trunc(11.111));
```

Comment: I just find out it fails on trunc(2.9999999999999999999999) = 3. I really hate JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
Number(amount_to_truncate.toFixed(2))
```

If you are sure that your input always will be lower or equal than `21474836.47` (`(2^31 - 1) / 100`) (32bit) then:

if you need as string (to make sure result will have 2 decimals)

```
((amount_to_truncate * 100|0)/100).toFixed(2)
```

Otherwise

```
((amount_to_truncate * 100|0)/100)
```

Else: See **[Nina Schols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41173031/104468)**'s answer

```js
console.log((((15.555 * 100)|0)/100)) // will not round: 15.55
console.log((((15 * 100)|0)/100).toFixed(2)) // will not round: 15.55
```

Comment: The OP wants to truncate the result. `toFixed` will round instead.

Comment: @MichaelLiu answer is updated. I still insist with `toFixed`

Comment: `((2.28 * 100|0)/100).toFixed(2)` outputs "2.27" because 
`console.log(2.28 * 100);` outputs 227.99999999999997.

`Number(2.286.toFixed(2))` outputs 2.29 because toFixed rounds @TolgahanAlbayrak

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for a non rounded number.

```js
console.log(parseInt(15.555 * 100, 10) / 100); // 15.55 no rounding
console.log((15.555 * 100 | 0) / 100);         // 15.55 no rounding, 32 bit only 
console.log((15.555).toFixed(2));              // 15.56 rounding
```

Comment: This yields a surprising result for large numbers like 1000000000000000000000. It may be safer to avoid using `parseInt`.

Comment: the value is unlikely for *money*, as OP mentioned.

Comment: `console.log((15 * 100 | 0) / 100); ` will output 15 instead of `15.00`

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak, the result, you mentioned, is only possible with a string.

Comment: You right. I missed that! Let me update my answer then :).

Comment: `console.log(parseInt(2.28 * 100, 10) / 100); // 2.27` because `console.log(2.28 * 100); // 227.99999999999997` @NinaScholz

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of [floating point arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I see wrong with `toFixed` is that it rounds the precision which OP specifically states they don't want to do. Truncate is more equivalent to `floor` for positive numbers and `ceil` for negative than `round` or `toFixed`. On the MDN page for the [Math.trunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) there is a polyfill replacement function that would do what OP is expecting.

```
Math.trunc = Math.trunc || function(x) {
  return x - x % 1;
}
```

If you just used that, then the code wouldn't have to change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toFixed):

```
number.toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parseInt to truncate, then divide by 100 and parseFloat.

```
var num = 123.4567;
num=parseInt(num*100);
num=parseFloat(num/100);
alert(num);
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r53u78er/)

Edit: in order to deal with javascript math craziness, you can use .toFixed and an additional digit of multiplication/division:

```
var num = 123.4567;
num = (num*1000).toFixed();
num = parseInt(num/10);
num = parseFloat(num/100);
alert(num);
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r53u78er/1/)

Comment: Same problem as the other answers, it fails on specific cases like 2.28 because 2.28 * 100 = 227.99999999999997 so is num = 2.28 the end result would be 2.27

Comment: Why would 2.28 * 100 be equal to 227.99999999999997?

Comment: I don't know, JavaScript reasons. Try it in a console and you'll see.

Comment: I am only just finding out about this oddity in javascript math.  Here's a workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/r53u78er/1/

Answer (score 0):

Truncate does also a rounding, so your statement: *"I need numbers to have only 2 decimals ... without rounding the decimals"* seems to me a little bit convoluted and would lead to a long discussion.

Beside this, when dealing with money, the problem isn't  `Math` but how you are using it. I suggest you read the [Floating-point cheat sheet for JavaScript](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/javascript/) - otherwise you will fail even with a simple calculation  like `1.40 - 1.00`.

The solution to your question is to use a well-tested library for arbitrary-precision decimals like [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) or [decimals.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/) (just as an example).

EDIT:

If you absolutely need a snippet, this is how i did it some time ago:

```
function round2(d) { return Number(((d+'e'+2)|0)+'e-'+2); }
```

Comment: You are probably right, but I can't (or shouldn't) add additional libraries to this particular project. Looks like [manonthemat answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41173276/4275425) is the only one that works so far.

Comment: @DavidPrieto: THX for your feedback, as i'm also truly interested in this topic, could you please kindly explain me where my round2() function fails against your accepted trunc() function? It's just onlly because you don't need the Math library or do you have found some other issues?

Comment: I'm seeing your edit just now. It looks like both functions work basically the same way, and I just tested that they both fail in round2(2.9999999999999999999999) = 3

Answer (score 0):

This was a lot easier than I thought:

```
const trunc = (number, precision) => {
  let index = number.toString().indexOf(".");
  let subStr;

  // in case of no decimal
  if (index === -1) {
    subStr = number.toString();
  }
  // in case of 0 precision
  else if (precision === 0) {
    subStr = number.toString().substring(0, index);
  }
  // all else
  else {
    subStr = number.toString().substring(0, index + 1 + precision);
  }
  return parseFloat(subStr);
};

let x = trunc(99.12, 1);

console.log("x", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
function trunc(value){
    return (!!value && typeof value == "number")? value - value%1 : 0;
}
console.log(trunc(1.4));
console.log(trunc(111.9));
console.log(trunc(0.4));
console.log(trunc("1.4"));
```